# Improvement: decoupled jre version for installer and application possible?

Tags: install4j

For now it seems to be impossible the decouple the jre for the main application from the jre used by the installer/updater itself. But sometimes there is a reason to use two different jre/jdk. Maybe the application needs java 8 and the installer is built with java 7 or older. Or maybe there are two applications to install which use two different java versions. Another idea is to create some kind of a meta installer that decide during runtime whether to install 32bit or 64bit java depend on the underlying platform architecture? The installer itself then has to use a 32bit version. So what about to decouple it and configure the jre for the application launchers itself independend from the java version of the installer/updater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with version 6.1.2 the launcher wizard will have an option to configured the JRE search sequence differently from the installer.

The setting will be available under the "Java invocation->Override Java version" step.

Comment: That sounds great and we will looking forward to the new version.